# What is a pre-memory read in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

An [article I saw today](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3514_7-57577639/samsung-joins-mozillas-quest-for-rust/) talks about the Rust programming language (being developed by Mozilla) and how it intends to replace C++.  One of the cited benefits of Rust is the lack of **pre-memory reads**.  Quoting Mozilla CTO Brendan Eich...

> "There's no pre-memory reads" in Rust, he said, but there are in C++. Those problems "lead to a lot of browser vulnerabilities" and would be solved by Rust.

Interestingly, there are only 4 hits on Google right now for the phrase "pre-memory reads", all of which refer to the article itself.  What is a pre-memory read in C++ and why is it bad?

Comment: I think you'll need to wait for Brendan Eich to clarify what he means. As far as I know, the phrase has no commonly understood meaning with respect to C++.

Comment: can you link the article?

Comment: @Dave This is the only hit which comes up on Google when I searched for the quote: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3514_7-57577639/samsung-joins-mozillas-quest-for-rust/

Comment: We went through the same kind of thing with Java over the past ten years: lots of hype, lots of ignorant bashing of C++, and ten years of setbacks for programmers who thought they had the magic bullet.

Comment: Looks like the original article has been updated: "There's no free memory reads" in Rust, he said, but there are in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There appears to have been a correction to the article. The [corrected quote](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3514_7-57577639/samsung-joins-mozillas-quest-for-rust/?part=rss&subj=cnet&tag=title&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20cnet/NnTv%20%28CNET%20River%20RSS%29) is as follows:

> He noted that every year browsers fall victim to hacking in the annual Pwn2Own contest at the CanSecWest conference. "There's no **free memory reads**" in Rust, he said, but there are in C++. Those problems "lead to a lot of browser vulnerabilities" and would be solved by Rust, which is a self-compiling language.

I think this explains it.

Comment: The quote in your link says "pre-memory reads" (as per the OP), not "free memory reads". Where are you seeing that?

Comment: @JBentley: I've tried opening the link in my answer using various browsers (including Chrome in Incognito mode), and every single time I see "free memory reads". At the same time the link in the question shows "pre-memory reads". No idea what's going on.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as @NPE - "There's no free memory reads" in Rust, he said

Comment: In any event, I think it is pretty safe to conclude that no one (except perhaps the reporter) said anything about "pre-memory reads".

Comment: @JBentley There was a correction to the article. The corrected version reads ["free memory reads"](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3514_7-57577639/samsung-joins-mozillas-quest-for-rust/?part=rss&subj=cnet&tag=title&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20cnet/NnTv%20%28CNET%20River%20RSS%29). The original version says ["pre-memory reads"](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-3514_7-57577639/samsung-joins-mozillas-quest-for-rust/).

Comment: This email clearly indicates it is `free memory reads` and gives an explanation of the concern (virtual calls): http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.devel.servo/17

Comment: Ok, now I'm seeing it as "free memory reads". Perhaps I was originally viewing a cached version.

Answer (score 6):

That article also contains this quote, which is clearly wrong:

> C++ is unsafe by design," he said. "It gets you down to the metal," a
>   term that means that the code runs natively and doesn't have to be
>   compiled before the CPU can understand it, "but it is unsafe.

So, I think it's safe to say that article is unreliable, and has possibly mis-quoted him.

Comment: "gets down to the metal" has always meant having low-level access to hardware. Which C++ has. At least down to memory address level (obviously C++ memory model doesn't give access down to register level without compiler extensions). But even if we take your definition, it's true. Code compiled by C++ can run natively on the CPU. Unlike Java for example.

Comment: @slebetman I don't understand your comment. I did not provide my own definiton, and the quote I referenced states that C++ code can be understood by the CPU *without* being compiled.

Comment: Ah. OK. So the article's author doesn't know what he's talking about.